# How to access HP QC(Quality Center 10.0) from Java Application

Tags: ota, hp-quality-center

I am working on java aplication, and i want to access HP QC(10) ALM from my java applicatoin,so that i can access all TestSet Folder,Test Set and Test from HP QC. What are tha APIs excluding REST APIs, since REST APIs does not support for QC 10,Does any body know complete tutorial for the same.

Answer (score 0):

otaclient9-2 and com4j will do the work. There are good samples around the web.